# Is there a way to register queries in SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite

Instead of writing...

```
SELECT {long ass list of crap}
FROM long_table_name
WHERE {annoyingly complex criteria} = 1
```

...every time it's required, is there a way to register this query? A sort of `CREATE_QUERY` command, if you will?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make a source file, `query.sql` containing all of your above query, then each time, do `USE query.sql;`. Or, you can store it in a python string, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [view](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT {long ass list of crap}
FROM long_table_name
WHERE {annoyingly complex criteria} = 1;
```

Afterwards, you can simply write `SELECT * FROM view_name`

Comment: Do `views` also support non-`SELECT` queries as well (i.e., `DELETE`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE`)?

Comment: @NoobSaibot: Not directly, but you can define a [`TRIGGER`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) with an `INSTEAD OF` clause for `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE`.

Comment: Would you mind appending your answer with an example of how to use `INSTEAD OF` in this case? I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create stored procedure in SQLite, instead you do some of this

1. Create a table or separate database where you can store your query and retrieve them using  a unique key or name
2. Create a file and retrieve them
3. Hard code them in your application
4. Create class that do the query and call it when you need it with input parameter(if necessary)